# adding a filter to a shortcode?

Tags: php, functions, filters

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[mingleforum]'); ?>
```

inserts the mingle forum into my content!

is it possible to use add_filter() on that?

Comment: To filter what? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This plugin uses a lot of weird and bad inline styles like `<div style="padding:10px"` etc. I want to get rid of that on the serverside. I just wonder if that's possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code to this:

```
<?php
$shortcode = do_shortcode('[mingleforum]');
echo apply_filters('my_new_filter',$shortcode);
?>
```

and then you can interact with that filter

```
add_filter('my_new_filter','my_new_filter_callback');

function my_new_filter_callback($shortcode){
    //to stuff here
    return $shortcode;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As of 4.7 two filters [`pre_do_shortcode_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_do_shortcode_tag/) and [`do_shortcode_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_shortcode_tag/) have been added which you can use.